# Fetch a label from tableView cell iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my application I'm adding a label to tableView cells using "cell addsubview" and not "cell.contentview addsubview". I'm assigning a tag to that label, but I'm not able to fetch it using "cell.contentView viewWithTag:1".

I perfectly understand that the label is not on contentView, but then how do I fetch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that label is a descendant view of the cell, not the content view, use:

```
[cell viewWithTag:1]
```